# Avoid reloading Pandas dataFrame if already in name space

Tags: python, pandas

Everytime i run my script the (very large) dataset is being reloaded. This is a time consuming and inefficient process which i want to avoid. So I was trying to get around the reloading by checking if the dataFrame already exists in the name space with the `try/except` command, looking like this:

```
try: 
    df.tail()
except NameError:
    df = pd.read_excel(...)
```

For the check the `tail` function is used, considering it an 'inexpensive' operation.

Anyways... Doesn't work. Are there any hints or suggestions on how to solve this? Or is there even a built-in *pandas* functionality that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

you could check using:

```
cond = 'df' in dir()
if cond:  
   # operate on data
else: 
   # load the data
```